# Q: Looking for name of technique or specific software for easy search and filtering on databases

Tags: database, search-engine, bigdata, querying

I am looking for the name or specific software for easy search and filtering on databases.

So for example i have a huge database. I want to point an application to it and that this application is smart enough to make automatic search options (based on table fields), filters and sorting available on the table.

Basically I just want easy querying without programming it manually and without the application knowing too much about the database.

Is this possible? Is there something like this? A framework or something similar.

I wish i knew the name for this then i could just google for it...

Comment: Wrong place to ask, try at http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to minimize programming. There is a large domain of software tools, which try to help you to do just that - [Computer-Aided Software Engineering (CASE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-aided_software_engineering).

Also you can find many CASE tools which will help you to create SQL code to access a relational database, however many of them concentrate only on data modeling and database creation/management.